# Movie clip node in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I'm compositing a 3d creature onto a live action plate that I wish you use with the movie clip node, which has worked fine for one movie clip, but when I try to change the clip it doesn't appear. Does anybody know why blender only seems to recognise the first video clip I added and no others. (In cycles and video clips are the same format)

Comment: Could you post a picture of your nodes? Is the video clip used as a texture on a plane or is it just compositing you're dealing with? Please elaborate on your question.